# How to assign instance variables as default values for keyword arguments in the same class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, instance-variables, self, keyword-argument

In Python 3.3+, given a class with a method, the class has an instance variable, which is a simple object() object (we'll call it self.FALSE). How do I use that instance variable as a default value for a keyword argument?

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.FALSE=object();
    def Tester(self, key=self.FALSE):
        pass;
```

This, of course, doesn't work because the scope of keyword argument default values does not include self (nor does it include the Test class generally). It does include global variables and at least some objects, however.

Is there a way to do this? I don't have a dire need, right now, but it would be really nice if I could do that, somehow. I would think you would be able to pass anything in as a keyword argument default value. Surely there must be a way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Initially have the default of value `key` as `None` and in the function, if `key` is `None`, then you can set the default value, whatever you like.

```
def Tester(self, key=None):
    if key is None:
        key = self.FALSE
```

Also, you don't need semicolons in Python, like we need in C/C++/JAVA.

Comment: I know you don't need semi-colons, but you can use them, and I actually encountered a very-difficult-to-decipher bug that occurred without them (not with them). I don't suppose that problem occurs often (and maybe not at all in new versions of Python), but once is enough for me to be concerned. That's why I like to use them. Plus, they clarify code, in my mind.

Comment: Your answer does explain a way to do what I asked. I already knew that approach, although I don't know if I was applying it to what I had in mind; so, it's a good reminder. (My situation was complex; so, I restructured it—but I thought I'd ask the question anyway, to see if there were more ways to deal with it.)

Comment: `if not key: ...`

Comment: @Zephir careful when you want to pass an empty string, empty collection, the number 0, False, etc to that keyword -- use x is None unless you want that behaviour

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way, because instance attributes do not exist until an instance is created, but the methods are defined when the class is created, before any instances exist.  That is, saying (as you do in your question) that "the class has an instance variable" is incorrect.  The class has no such thing; only the instances have that variable, and only if and when they are created.

You must do as thefourtheye suggests and handle assigning a default inside the method body.

Comment: Thanks for the note about instance variables. It's logically obvious, but I just looked at the word 'instance' as an abstract symbol; so, I didn't realize it. (Note that I can't give you points at this point, because of my new reputation. So, you'll have to accept thanks until then.)